# Functions not being called correctly

Tags: python, function, loops

This is a code that prompts the user for the amount of months they want to budget analyze, prompts for the budget the user has, prompts for how much the user spent that month, and then calculates if the user is over or under their budget. When code is run, it prompts user one twice, and then creates errors:

```py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\", line 51, in main
    AnalyzeBudget(months)
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\", line 46, in AnalyzeBudget
    MoBudget,MoSpent = GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month)
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\", line 40, in GetMonthBudgetandSpent
    return int(Mobudget, MoSpent)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

any help is appreciated.

```
def DescribeProgram():
 
   print("""\
This program uses a for loop to monitor your budget.
The program will prompt you to enter your budget, and amount spent
for a certain month and calculate if your were under or over budget.
You will have the option of choosing how many months you would like to
monitor.\n""")


def GetMonths():
    Months = input("Enter the number of months you want to analyze")
    return int(Months)

def GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month):
      Mobudget = input("Enter the budget you have for the month")
      MoSpent = input("Enter the amount you spent this month")
      return int(Mobudget, MoSpent)

def AnalyzeBudget(months):
    for month in range(1,months+1):
      print("\nMonth",month,":")
      print("=======")
      MoBudget,MoSpent = GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month)

def main():
 DescribeProgram()
 months = GetMonths()
 AnalyzeBudget(months)

main()
```

Comment: Did you mean: `return int(Months)`?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana sorry! i added the error traceback, and added the int(months) to the code.  still having problems

Comment: You can't give two strings to `int()` and expect two integers. That is not how `int` works. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int. The _first_ argument is the object you want to convert to an integer. The second argument is the _base_ of the number system

Comment: Why did you add `int()`? Did you mean: `return Mobudget, MoSpent`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return type of `GetMonths()` :

```
def GetMonths():
    Months = input("Enter the number of months you want to analyze")
    return int(Months)
```

Or You can cast the type to int in `range()` of `AnalyzeBudget()`

```
def AnalyzeBudget(months):
    for month in range(1,int(months)+1):
      print("\nMonth",month,":")
      print("=======")
      MoBudget,MoSpent = GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @quamrana said you need to

```
def GetMonths():
    Months = input("Enter the number of months you want to analyze")
    return int(Months)
```

The error says `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str` because when you ask for Months in

```
Months = input("Enter the number of months you want to analyze")
```

Python read the input as a string, then in `months+1` you are adding a string with an int so you get the error.
I recommend to factorize your code in an class where each function is a method, I can help you with this if you need to.

Edit(This is not related to the original post).
You have an error in GetMonthBudgetandSpent, you can do the following.

```
def GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month):
  Mobudget = input("Enter the budget you have for the month")
  MoSpent = input("Enter the amount you spent this month")
  MoSpent = int(MoSpent)
  Mobudget = int(Mobudget)
  return Mobudget, MoSpent
```

As @Pranav Hosangadi said int function [int docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) takes in the first input of the thing you want to convert, so you can only pass one string.

For the if statement you asked for in the comments.

```
def AnalyzeBudget(months):
for month in range(1,months+1):
  print("\nMonth",month,":")
  print("=======")
  MoBudget,MoSpent = GetMonthBudgetandSpent(month)
  if MoBudget >= MoSpent:
    print("Safe zone")
  else :
    print("Danger zone")
```

Here `if MoBudget >= MoSpent` checks if the budget is more than spent in that month, if so then print "safe zone", else (MoSpent > Mobudget) then print "Danger zone"

Comment: Im confused on how to write the if else code that prints if the user is over or under budget in the AnaylzeBudget function how would i do that?